# Cells in Excel._Worksheet do not correctly filled with data

Tags: c#, wpf, excel, export-to-excel

In my post at '[How to export DateTime, TimeSpan, string and double values to Excel from WPF MVVM application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39847939/how-to-export-datetime-timespan-string-and-double-values-to-excel-from-wpf-mvv)' I ask about how to do export in MS Excel from WPF MVVM application using VSTO. Not waiting for an answer, I decided to try myself to do it. I have 'MS Excel 2016 MSO (16.0.4432.1000) 64-bite version' on my computer. I have been writing the folowing code to implement export.

```
    // Exports to MS Excel.
    private async void exportToExcel()
    {
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            // Cell index.
            int cellIndex = 2;
            // MS Excel application instance.
            Excel.Application oXL = null;
            // Work book.
            Excel._Workbook oWB;
            // Active work sheet.
            Excel._Worksheet oSheet;
            // Cell range.
            Excel.Range oRng;
            // Next sheet index.
            int sheetIndex = 2;

            try
            {
                //Start Excel and get Application object.
                oXL = new Excel.Application();
                oXL.Visible = false;
                //Get a new workbook.
                oWB = oXL.Workbooks.Add(Missing.Value);
                // Get shets quantity.
                int sheetsQuantity = oWB.Sheets.Count;
                // Get active sheet.
                oSheet = (Excel._Worksheet)oWB.ActiveSheet;

                //Add table headers going cell by cell.
                oSheet.Cells[1, 1] = "Date";
                oSheet.Cells[1, 2] = "Time";
                oSheet.Cells[1, 3] = "Beam";
                oSheet.Cells[1, 4] = "Direction";
                oSheet.Cells[1, 5] = "Value";
                //Format A1:E1 as bold, vertical alignment = center.
                oSheet.get_Range("A1", "E1").Font.Bold = true;
                oSheet.get_Range("A1", "E1").VerticalAlignment = Excel.XlVAlign.xlVAlignCenter;

                // Get name of file to export to Excel.
                string fileDateTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd.mm.yyyy hh:mm:ss");
                fileDateTime = fileDateTime.Replace(".", "");
                fileDateTime = fileDateTime.Replace(":", "");
                fileDateTime = fileDateTime.Replace(' ', '_');
                string fileName = "test_" + fileDateTime + ".xlsx";

                // Exporting in Excel.
                while (this._isAbsoluteChartDataBeingExported)
                {
                    AGC_DataRecordToSave record;
                    if (this._agcAbsoluteDataRecordsToSaveBuf.TryDequeue(out record))
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            oSheet.Range["A" + cellIndex].Value = record.Date.ToString("d");
                            oSheet.Range["B" + cellIndex].Value = record.Time.ToString("T");
                            oSheet.Range["C" + cellIndex].Value = record.MeasuringBeam.ToString();
                            oSheet.Range["D" + cellIndex].Value = record.Direction;
                            oSheet.Range["E" + cellIndex].Value = record.Value;
                        }
                        catch(COMException)
                        {
                            //AutoFit columns A:E.
                            oRng = oSheet.get_Range("A1", "E1");
                            oRng.EntireColumn.AutoFit();

                            // If sheets number more than one.
                            if (sheetsQuantity > 1)
                            {
                                // If next sheet index is less than quantity of sheets then get next sheet and activate it.
                                if (sheetIndex < sheetsQuantity)
                                {
                                    oSheet = oWB.Sheets[sheetIndex];
                                    oSheet.Activate();
                                    sheetIndex += 1;

                                    cellIndex = 2;
                                    //Add table headers going cell by cell.
                                    oSheet.Cells[1, 1] = "Date";
                                    oSheet.Cells[1, 2] = "Time";
                                    oSheet.Cells[1, 3] = "Beam";
                                    oSheet.Cells[1, 4] = "Direction";
                                    oSheet.Cells[1, 5] = "Value";
                                    //Format A1:E1 as bold, vertical alignment = center.
                                    oSheet.get_Range("A1", "E1").Font.Bold = true;
                                    oSheet.get_Range("A1", "E1").VerticalAlignment = Excel.XlVAlign.xlVAlignCenter;
                                    continue;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    // Else, add new sheet in workbook.
                                    oWB.Sheets.Add(Missing.Value, oSheet, 1, Excel.XlSheetType.xlWorksheet);
                                    oSheet = oWB.Sheets[2];
                                    oSheet.Visible = Excel.XlSheetVisibility.xlSheetHidden;
                                    sheetsQuantity += 1;
                                    sheetIndex += 1;

                                    cellIndex = 2;
                                    //Add table headers going cell by cell.
                                    oSheet.Cells[1, 1] = "Date";
                                    oSheet.Cells[1, 2] = "Time";
                                    oSheet.Cells[1, 3] = "Beam";
                                    oSheet.Cells[1, 4] = "Direction";
                                    oSheet.Cells[1, 5] = "Value";
                                    //Format A1:E1 as bold, vertical alignment = center.
                                    oSheet.get_Range("A1", "E1").Font.Bold = true;
                                    oSheet.get_Range("A1", "E1").VerticalAlignment = Excel.XlVAlign.xlVAlignCenter;
                                    continue;
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                // Else, add new sheet in workbook.
                                oWB.Sheets.Add(Missing.Value, oSheet, 1, Excel.XlSheetType.xlWorksheet);
                                oSheet = oWB.Sheets[2];
                                oSheet.Visible = Excel.XlSheetVisibility.xlSheetHidden;
                                sheetsQuantity += 1;
                                sheetIndex += 1;

                                cellIndex = 2;
                                //Add table headers going cell by cell.
                                oSheet.Cells[1, 1] = "Date";
                                oSheet.Cells[1, 2] = "Time";
                                oSheet.Cells[1, 3] = "Beam";
                                oSheet.Cells[1, 4] = "Direction";
                                oSheet.Cells[1, 5] = "Value";
                                //Format A1:E1 as bold, vertical alignment = center.
                                oSheet.get_Range("A1", "E1").Font.Bold = true;
                                oSheet.get_Range("A1", "E1").VerticalAlignment = Excel.XlVAlign.xlVAlignCenter;
                                continue;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    cellIndex++;
                }

                // Save work book in XLSX-file.
                if (!File.Exists(Path.Combine(this.PathToCsvRepository, fileName)))
                    oWB.SaveAs(Path.Combine(this.PathToCsvRepository, fileName), Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, true, true, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange,
                        Excel.XlSaveConflictResolution.xlLocalSessionChanges, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, true);
            }
            catch (IOException ex)
            {
                string errorMessage = string.Empty;
                errorMessage = string.Concat(errorMessage, ex.Message);
                errorMessage = string.Concat(errorMessage, " Line: ");
                errorMessage = string.Concat(errorMessage, ex.Source);
                MessageBox.Show(errorMessage, "Ошибка");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string errorMessage = string.Empty;
                errorMessage = string.Concat(errorMessage, ex.Message);
                errorMessage = string.Concat(errorMessage, " Line: ");
                errorMessage = string.Concat(errorMessage, ex.Source);
                MessageBox.Show(errorMessage, "Ошибка");
            }
            finally
            {
                // Complete work with Excel.
                CloseExcel(oXL);
            }
        });
    }
```

Where _agcAbsoluteDataRecordsToSaveBuf is ConcurrentQueue instance and _isAbsoluteChartDataBeingExported is the boolean flag which is set when user turns on export to MS Excel and unset when the user turns off this export. And below is the method for closing Excel:

```
    // Closes Excel.
    private static void CloseExcel(Excel.Application theApp)
    {
        int id = 0;
        IntPtr intptr = new IntPtr(theApp.Hwnd);
        System.Diagnostics.Process p = null;
        try
        {
            GetWindowThreadProcessId(intptr, out id);
            p = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessById(id);
            if (p != null)
            {
                p.Kill();
                p.Dispose();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("CloseExcel:" + ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

What I need is: 1) Create the header for the table on active WorkSheet and define the name for XLSX-file. 2) Сontinually poll the ConcurrentQueue instanse for existing data while _isAbsoluteChartDataBeingExported == true. 3) Take current instance of AGC_DataRecordToSave (record to export) from the ConcurrentQueue instance. 4) Take the values of the fields from this AGC_DataRecordToSave instance and asign these field values to WorkSheet's cells by appropriate index for the cells (cellIndex variable). 5) Correct the index for the cells and poll the ConcurrentQueue instance again for new record. E.t.c. When the number of rows on current active sheet reachs a limit (COMException is thrown) go to the next Sheet of WorkBook (make this list active) and repeat again 2) - 5) items. E.t.c. When user turns export to MS Excel off write WorkBook (with Sheets with data) to XLSX-file. But I can not achieve the desired effect. Below is how the result is seen in MS Excel.

[image]
And only the first sheet has data. All remaining sheets are empty. And yet, as you can see, an uneven enumeration of sheets has place (1, 2, 109, 108,...). But the numeration of sheets must be the following (1, 2, 3, 4, ...). What i'm doing wrong? Please help me to correct and eliminate the errors and get 'exportToExcel' method to work correctly.

Answer (score 1):

There is a easy way to use [npoi.mapper](https://github.com/donnytian/Npoi.Mapper) with just below 2 lines. And it does not require to install MS Office on the server.

```
var mapper = new Mapper();
mapper.Save("test.xlsx",  objects, "newSheet");
```

Comment: I bag your pardon, DonnyTian, but I don't ask about which library is better, I've asked what I should do in my code to get the correct result.